# How to start node.js server on Azure Web App service?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, api, server

I have a create-my-react bootstrapped application that is essentially a website that uses some FETCH API calls to a external API and it is deployed and works fine.

However, I added my own Nodejs backend,  by creating a server and using using express for the routes/middleware. Everything works fine locally. I can hit my internal API endpoints (localhost:3000/myapiurlhere) and it performs an action on a database.

I have to run `npm start` to start up the create-my-react-app locally and then manually run the node server by `node src/server.js` then my internal API works.

The Azure Web App service is basically a preconfigured server with the Node RUNTIME on it, and it only seems to give you access to the D:\home\site\wwwroot folder (Windows server).

Do I need to find a way to run `node server.js` command on the server to start my node backend, or should it be running automatically? Also, I'm using create-my-react-app and `npm run build` , so it creates a `build` folder with a nested `static` folder.

I have started up REST APIs on Java on my Linux Ubuntu servers before but never on an App Service like Azure. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Here is my `server.js` file:

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to do anything special, Have you followed [`this page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs) on how to deploy basic nodejs app on Azure AppService?

One additional thing you need to do is that pass the Node version on appsettings of the appservice.

**`WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`** for the setting key.

Comment: once you do the above enable logging to see what is happening https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Troubleshooting-Node-errors

Comment: Ok i'm looking at that page. Normally on a  Ubuntu server with Apache Webserver installed or something, I would have to manually start or "boot" the Nodejs server by running the command "node src/server.js" the path to my server.js file . How does Azure do this automatically and know what my file is called? Even when I run locally, if I don't run this file, none of my node/express APIs work because there is no node/backend server running